# Gridgain: Query running slow

Tags: gridgain

I'm using Gridgain 6.5.5 version with 3 nodes(on same host).

I'm performing the following tests:

Test 1:

1. Load data using GridDataLoader initially from a .csv file.
2. Run sample queries.

Test 2:

1. With the data loaded, I'm trying to run the same queries.

Even if I don't load the data, Gridgain is taking more time (> 10 min)to execute the query

The config file I'm using the example-cache.xml.

Is it because of some configuration errors?

Comment: Query execution should not take longer than a few milliseconds. Can you please paste the query you are executing? Also, how much data is being loaded into cache (do you have enough memory)?

Comment: Cache Nodes: 3, Total Heap Capacity: 29.4GB Total Caches Size: 5.5GB Total Caches: 2 Total Heap Used: 21.7GB Total Caches Keys: 8.5M. Query is select sum(salary), min(salary), max(salary) from Person. In the SQL Viewer of Visor, It takes ~58s. But from the Java code it takes more than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Given the heapsize I guess GC pauses could be one of the reasons.

Comment: So the solution is to increase the Heap Size? Is there any formula for Memory and Heap size to get better performance for Gridgain?

Comment: @Anju I am not a gridgain expert but I would try to use off-heap memory and to see if it gets faster.

Comment: I used off-heap with these 2 properties in the config file
<property name="offHeapMaxMemory" value="#{10 * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L}"/>
<property name="memoryMode" value="OFFHEAP_TIERED"/> .             Now the time to execute the query is ~ 2 min, Which is still slow

Comment: I would add more nodes per server. If you have N cores, try starting (N - 1) number of GridGain nodes per server. This way you will add more parallelism to the query and it should run faster.